# Eindhoven public transport

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, eindhoven

I'm going to Eindhoven this weekend, there's a hotel close to where I need to be, but not really walking distance. The bus stops seems really conveniently placed though, with service from *Connexxion*.

How can I pay for a CXX bus in Eindhoven?

Travel Advisor's 'information' on it is just that "you will want to buy a Nationale Strippen Kart". It doesn't mention if that's the only option, or if just an assertion that that's what I'll want to do.

Can I pay cash onboard?

Since any "... from a bus station" or even "... at a supermarket" solution is less than convenient.

Or failing that - what's the prevalence/affordability of taxis in the city?

Comment: Taxis are expensive, think €7.50 for a short distance, starting fee, and going up as soon as you go over the starting distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I live in Eindhoven and you can pay in cash. The bus costs 3,50 euro's, no matter where you get off the bus.

The OV-Chipkaart is a much cheaper option. For more information, go to [this](https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/aanvragen/welkekaartpastbiju/toeristen/?taal=en) website.

You can use the website [www.9292ov.nl](http://www.9292ov.nl/en) to plan your travel using public transport. The site is also available in English and it will show you the costs if you are using an OV-chipkaart.

Comment: Note that you can just buy an OV-chip card from a vending machine at the station. This will be €7.50, so it will only be cheaper if you travel a bunch of times with the bus (or train).

Answer (score 0):

The 'Nationale Strippenkaart' was discontinued in 2011. In Dutch:

http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationale_Strippenkaart

You need an OV-Chipkaart, a contactless smart card. In English:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OV-chipkaart

I suppose it's possible there are some bus lines that accept cash, but that would be an obscure exception. As the above links points out, the OV-chikaart is used in all Dutch public transport.

Comment: As far as I know all bus lines in the Eindhoven area at least can be paid for with cash (perhaps not so in other area's?). I did so last week ;-) It's just much more expensive

Comment: Well, shows what I know. Do you actually pay with the driver, or do you pay a machine at the bus stop?

Comment: You can pay the driver. At some stops (notably the airport) you have to get a ticket from a machine outside.

Comment: In some regions Connexxion does specials like 'cheaper after 9 AM' so it might be that paying cash works out better than buying a OV chip card longer than you would expect.